# differents push notification for open differents activity

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I was able to push notifications for messages (MessageActivity) and I want to use this to make also that of my comments on posts (CommentsActivity) when a user comments we get the push notification too (like Facebook , Instagram...) , please help me

is it possible to also do the push notification for those whose comments are posted from here << MyFirebaseMessaging >>? if so please help ...

MyFirebaseMessaging

```
package com.developer.fireone.finga.Notifications;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;


import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.developer.fireone.finga.MainActivity;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.MessageActivity;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

/**
 * Created by user on 13/02/2019.
 */

public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    // notify msg...
    String sented = remoteMessage.getData().get("sented");
    String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String currentUser= preferences.getString("currentuser","none");

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


    if(firebaseUser!=null && sented.equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
        if(!currentUser.equals(user)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                sendOreoNotification(remoteMessage);

            } else {
                sendNotification(remoteMessage);

            }

        }
    }


}

private void sendOreoNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
    String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
    String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("userid", user);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,j,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    OreoNotification oreoNotification = new OreoNotification(this);
    Notification.Builder builder = oreoNotification.getOreoNotification(title, body, pendingIntent,
            defaultSound, icon);

    int i = 0;
    if(j>0){
        i=j;
    }

    oreoNotification.getManager().notify(i, builder.build());


}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
    String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
    String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("userid", user);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,j,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager noti = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int i = 0;
    if(j>0){
        i=j;
    }

    noti.notify(i, builder.build());


}
```

}

MyFirebaseIdService

```
package com.developer.fireone.finga.Notifications;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

/**
 * Created by user on 13/02/2019.
 */

public class MyFirebaseIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    String refreshToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    if(firebaseUser != null){
        updateToken(refreshToken);
    }

}

private void updateToken(String refreshToken) {

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens");
    Token token = new Token(refreshToken);
    reference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(token);


}
```

}